# how can I make remaining time and day in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have one event like running and this event have time and date (D.28/March/2016 kl. 10:40) and i wanna make something like how many hours remaining to this event for example 10 day 5 hours 35 minutes to forest to the bay event.and my DateTime came from database.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDqrJ.jpg)

Comment: Please create a [mcve] based on your problem. It is _really_ hard to tell what is wrong without any information.

Comment: i just attached image just click on it :)

Comment: Post the code in the question, don't force people to click on images. Otherwise the question is incomprehensible, unsearchable, and useless to people that may have the same question in the future. Which is why questions with links to images are considered Very Low Quality

Comment: A banner image with trees? Any reason this question shouldn't be flagged for deletion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
DateTime myDate =  DateTime.Parse("3/28/2016 10:40");

TimeSpan timeToEvent = myDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now);

string message = string.Format("Days : {0}, Hours : {1}, Minutes : {2}", 
                               timeToEvent.Days, timeToEvent.Hours, timeToEvent.Minutes);
Console.WriteLine(message);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `TimeSpan` class:

```
DateTime eventDate = new DateTime(2016, 3, 21, 12, 0, 0);
TimeSpan timeLeft = eventDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now);

Console.Write("{0} days {1} hours {2} minutes {3} seconds left",
              timeLeft.Days, timeLeft.Hours, timeLeft.Minutes, timeLeft.Seconds);
```